# How to add custom headers in the code pasted?

Tags: java, react-native

I've found some code in some library I've used, I wonder how can I add custom header

from the options. It should receive something from JS to native(Java). 
I'm not expert on Java. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the repository where it's coming from. https://github.com/tranquangvu/react-native-uploader/

```
 ...

@ReactMethod
  public void upload(ReadableMap options, Callback complete) {

    final Callback completeCallback = complete;

    try {
      MultipartBody.Builder mRequestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
              .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

      ReadableArray files = options.getArray("files");
      String url = options.getString("url");
      String method = options.getString("method");

      if(options.hasKey("params")){
        ReadableMap data = options.getMap("params");
        ReadableMapKeySetIterator iterator = data.keySetIterator();

        while(iterator.hasNextKey()){
          String key = iterator.nextKey();
          if(ReadableType.String.equals(data.getType(key))) {
            mRequestBody.addFormDataPart(key, data.getString(key));
          }
        }
      }

      if(files.size() != 0){
        for(int fileIndex=0 ; fileIndex<files.size(); fileIndex++){
          ReadableMap file = files.getMap(fileIndex);
          String uri = file.getString("filepath");

          Uri file_uri;
          if(uri.substring(0,10).equals("content://") ){
            file_uri = Uri.parse(convertMediaUriToPath(Uri.parse(uri)));
          }
          else{
            file_uri = Uri.parse(uri);
          }

          File imageFile = new File(file_uri.getPath());

          if(imageFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "FILE NOT FOUND");
            completeCallback.invoke("FILE NOT FOUND", null);
              return;
          }

          String mimeType = "image/png";
          if(file.hasKey("filetype")){
            mimeType = file.getString("filetype");
          }
          MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(mimeType);
          String fileName = file.getString("filename");
          String name = fileName;
          if(file.hasKey("name")){
            name = file.getString("name");
          }


          mRequestBody.addFormDataPart(name, fileName, RequestBody.create(mediaType, imageFile));
        }
      }

      MultipartBody requestBody = mRequestBody.build();
      Request request;

      // NOTE: The author seems added the header statically, I wonder how can I add a custom header.

      if(method.equals("PUT")) {
        request = new Request.Builder()
              .header("Accept", "application/json")
              .url(url)
              .put(requestBody)
              .build();
      }
      else{
        request = new Request.Builder()
              .header("Accept", "application/json")
              .url(url)
              .post(requestBody)
              .build();
      }   

      Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
      if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Unexpected code" + response);
          completeCallback.invoke(response, null);
          return;
      }

      completeCallback.invoke(null, response.body().string());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just instruct the `okhttp.Request.Builder` to insert one more header:

```
request = new Request.Builder()
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .header("X-example-header", "example-value")
    .url(url)
    .put(requestBody)
    .build();
```

Edit (example, dedicated to those who refuse to read the docs themselves):

Or use something like:

```
Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
    .header("Accept", "application/json");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    builder.header("X-example-header-" + i, "example-value-" + i)
}
request = builder
    .url(url)
    .put(requestBody)
    .build();
```

Comment: that would be the same as the author putting it statically, how would it be done like the params block, `if(options.hasKey("params")){` . It adds loops to add more key/value